# DatePickers on the FloatPanel

Tags: gwt, datepicker, panel

I need to place several DatePicker widgets into the row. If there is not enough width to place all of them the rest widgets shift to the next row. It is the default HTML layout behavior. So I am trying to use FlowPanel.  With any other widgets (Buttons, Labels, ...) everything ok, but DatePickers are placed one widget to the row. Here's the code

```
    FlowPanel panel = new FlowPanel();      
    DatePicker picker1 = new DatePicker();
    DatePicker picker2 = new DatePicker();      

    panel.add(picker1);
    panel.add(picker2);

    RootPanel.get().add(panel);
```

Any suggestions to solve this problem?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DatePicker`'s root element is a `table` so you'd have to give it a `display: inline-table` style, or put it in an element with `display: inline-block` style.

The following shouldn't break any other use of `DatePicker`, but won't work in IE 6 or 7; it's the Simplest Thing That Could Possibly Work™:

```
.gwt-DatePicker { display: inline-table; }
```

If you really need IE 6/7 support, you could try the following, in a CssResource:

```
@if user.agent ie6 {
   .gwt-DatePicker { display: inline; }
}
@else {
   .gwt-DatePicker { display: inline-table; }
}
```